# Is it possible to call a private constructor from a static method defined in the cpp?

Tags: c++

A C++ n00b question.  Is it possible to call a private constructor from a static method defined in the cpp?   I'd like to keep methods out of the header file if possible -- I figure there should be a way to do this.  I'm getting an error when attempting this:

"cannot access private member declared in class SomeClass"

```
/////////////////
// SomeClass.h //
/////////////////

class SomeClass {
    public:
        static SomeClass SomeMethod();
    private:
        SomeClass(int i);
}

///////////////////
// SomeClass.cpp //
///////////////////

static SomeClass OSImplementation() {
    return SomeClass(0);
};

// calls implementation
SomeClass SomeClass::SomeMethod() {
    return OSImplementation();
}
```

Comment: `OSImplementation` should be a friend then (assuming you can't make it a member).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make `OSImplementation` a friend method.

Or you can make `OSImplementation` a static method within the class (but that has to be declared in the header).

Or, probably the most common way to do this, is to have an internal implementation class, like  this:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    //...
private:
    struct Impl;
    Impl* intern;
};
```

In your cpp file, you declare `struct SomeClass::Impl`.

In your constructor, create the `SomeClass::Impl` instance. Delete it in the destructor. And implement the copy-constructor and the assignment operator!

This is called the PIMPL (pointer to implementation) idiom ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer), [c2.com](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom)). It's used a lot in big projects like Qt.

Comment: "_a static method within the class (but that has to be defined in the header)_" do you mean declared, not defined?

Comment: Is there any way to create a friend without defining it?  Maybe it'll just make the constructor public :)

Comment: @DanielH: You don't additionally need to declare the friended method in advance. However, that also has to be put into your header. If you have many such functions, that also becomes ugly. Also, you don't really gain anything from it, it probably makes more sense to just have it as a static method or a normal member method. But, if you want to have it really clean, with some additional effort, the PIMPL idiom is the way to go (there isn't really an alternative).

Comment: Thanks Albert -- very helpful.  How would one define a friend that's not in the header?

Comment: Just put `friend SomeClass OSImplementation();` into your class declaration (in the header). Thus, the `friend` itself has to be in the header.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, by making the `OSImplementation()` friend of SomeClass. Next example compiles without warnings and errors using g++ 4.6.1 :

```
#include <iostream>

// declare in hpp
class SomeClass {

   friend SomeClass OSImplementation();

    public:
        static SomeClass SomeMethod();

        void foo();

    private:
        SomeClass(int);
};


int main()
{
  auto obj = SomeClass::SomeMethod();

  obj.foo();
}

// define in cpp
SomeClass SomeClass::SomeMethod(){
  return SomeClass( 5 );
}

SomeClass::SomeClass(int){
}

void SomeClass::foo(){
  std::cout<<"foo"<<std::endl;
}

SomeClass OSImplementation()
{
  return SomeClass::SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: static file method defined in the cpp, not static to class.

Comment: @DanielH In your pseudo code, I see only `SomeMethod` as a static method in the header